# Derivative Riccati-Bessel function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

I have found two derivatives of the so-called Riccati-Bessel functions in a textbook

$$ (x j_n(x))'=xj_{n-1}(x)-nj_{n}(x)$$
and 
$$ (x h_n^{(1)}(x))'=x h_{n-1}^{(1)}(x)-n h_n^{(1)}(x)$$

so $j_n$ is the spherical bessel function of the 1st kind and $h_n$ is the spherical hankel function of the first kind.

Since these derivatives differ from what I would assume, I just wanted to ask you whether they are wrong?

Perhaps this is the result of a somewhat different calculation, so maybe he just differentiated the sph. bessel function and not the x in front, but anyway I would be interested if somebody here could check this.

Comment: With the standard definition $j_n(x) = \sqrt{\tfrac{1}{2}\pi x} J_{n+1/2}(x)$ and if Maple and I did not make any mistakes the first derivative relation should be 
$$ (x j_n(x))'=xj_{n-1}(x)-(n-1)j_{n}(x),$$ i.e. there should be an additional **-1** in the last term.

Comment: okay, then the probably the same is true for the hankel function, if you could check this too and post it as an answer, I could accept it as the right one ;-)

Comment: Sorry I did a mistaske,  $j_n(x) = \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2x}} J_{n+1/2}(x)$. Add with the corrected definition it seems to be correct.

Comment: alright, thanks then